# What changes when saving and loading a model using tf.saved_model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I was following the official TensorFlow quick start tutorial and I wanted to save and load the model, but the following code raises on the final line

```
ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(1, 28, 28), dtype=float64)
    * False
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}
```

with declaring a keras sequential model and saving like so:

```
print(model(x_train[:1]))
tf.saved_model.save(model, export_path)
loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load(export_path)
print(loaded_model(x_train[:1]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around the problem by using `model.save(export_path)` and `tf.keras.load_model(export_path)` respectively. The relevant documentation can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize).